# MySQL command line client for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows

Is there any nice command line MySQL client for windows? I mean a single exe that allows connecting and running a sample query. I've googled and only could find big graphical environments like toad or mysql workbench. I need only a simple command line tool, where can  I download sth like this?

EDIT: I don't want to install the whole MySQL package on my PC. I know it's inside the mysql package but how do I download only this cmd line client. Because i don't need anything else.

Comment: It looks like one should come with your MySQL install according to the MySQL [webpage](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/mysql-administrator-menus-tools-mysql-command-line-client.html). Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, but how can I download the client only? I don't want the whole database engine on my PC, i only need a command line client to connect to database on the other box.

Comment: If you have the database already installed, you must have mysql.exe already.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I would recommend downloading the [zip](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), getting the client, and then dumping the rest. :)

Comment: This question may be better suited to http://superuser.com as it isn't a programming question (but rather a "how do I install..." one)

Comment: MySQL already comes with a command line client. Most know that Mysql.exe on its own will launch you into an interactive console application. However, if you launch it with the -e parameter, you can specify an SQL statement which it will execute and then exit.
So, for example, if you wanted a count of records from your employees table, you would do this:

**mysql -e "select count(*) from companyDB.employees;"**

Answer (score 66, accepted):

When you go to the MySQL [download page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), choose the platform "Microsoft Windows". Then download the "Windows (x86, xx-bit), ZIP Archive" (be sure to select the one with size over 140M.

**The binaries will be in the "bin" folder.**

I understand that this is not just the client binaries, but at least you don't have to install and setup the entire server.

Comment: sql.exe and sql.pdb are the files you need.

Comment: Once I've downloaded it, how do I install just the client?

Comment: You don't need any special install procedure. Just run sql.exe from your command line (check your environment path if it doesn't run at first)

Comment: MySQL now only shows the .msi downloads by default - good to have that URL you provided to the zips!

Comment: Add the `bin` folder to your PATH and then access the MySQL shell with `mysqlsh --version` for example.

Comment: This does not seem to work on a clean Windows 10 installation. An error occurs, indicating that `VCRUNTIME140.dll` is missing.

Answer (score 29):

mysql.exe can do just that....

To connect,

`mysql -u root -p` (press enter)

It should prompt you to enter root password (u = username, p = password)

Then you can use SQL database commands to do pretty much anything....

Comment: This answer assumes the MySQL package is already installed, and the question is now to get the "mysql" executable *without* installing the whole MySQL package.

Comment: @DS, I answered this post **before** the EDIT.

Comment: By the way, you can execute mysql commands on the fly with `-e` param like: `mysql.exe -u root -e "select 'this is mysql batch script';"`

Answer (score 15):

You can choose only install the client during server install.  The website only offers to let you download the full installer (grab whatever version you want from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

In the install wizard, when prompted for installation type (typical, minimal, custom), choose 'Custom'.  On the next screen, select to NOT install the server, and proceed with the rest of the install as normal.

When you're done, you should see just the relevant client programs (mysql, mysqldump, etc) in C:\Program Files\MySQL..\bin

Comment: Actually at least now there's a lightweight installer download (net installer) of under 19MB

Answer (score 11):

Its pretty simple. I saved the mysql community server in my `D:\` drive. Hence this is how i did it.

Goto `D:\mysql-5.7.18-winx64\bin` and in the address bar type cmd and press enter, so command prompt will open. Now if you're using it for the first time type as `mysql -u root -p`press enter. Then it will ask for password, again press enter. Thats it you are connected to the mysql server.

`Before this make sure wamp or xampp any of the local server is running` because i couldn't able to connect to mysql wihthout xampp running.
[image]

[image]

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 10):

You can also download [MySql workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (31Mo) which includes `mysql.exe` and `mysqldump.exe`.

I successfully tested this when i had to run Perl scripts using `DBD:MySql` module to run SQL statements against a distant MySql db.

Answer (score 6):

You can access mySQL in command line just by typing:

```
C:\www\mysql\bin> mysql -u root -p
```

After which you can type sql commands normally such as:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
```

Here, I am assuming you mySQL installation directory is `C:\www\mysql`.

Comment: This answer assumes the MySQL package is already installed, and the question is now to get the "mysql" executable *without* installing the whole MySQL package.

Comment: I see that we have misunderstood you. Perhaps some sort of jdbc compliant client like squirrel-sql or try isolating the mysql client for the zip download.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar requirement where I need a MySQL client but not server (running in a virtual machine and don't want any additional overhead) and for me the easiest thing was to install MySQL community server taking typical installation options but NOT configure the server, so it never starts, never runs. Added C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin to system path environment variable and I'm able to use the MySQL command line client mssql.exe and mysqladmin.exe programs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for tools like the the mysql and mysqldump command line client for Windows for versions around *mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for Win32 (x86)* it seems to be in **HOMEDRIVE:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench version**

This directory is also not placed in the path by default so you will need to add it to your PATH environment variable before you can easily run it from the command prompt.

Also, there is a mysql utilities console but it does not work for my needs.  Below is a list of the capabilities on the mysql utilities console in case it works for you:

```
Utility           Description
----------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
mysqlauditadmin   audit log maintenance utility
mysqlauditgrep    audit log search utility
mysqldbcompare    compare databases for consistency
mysqldbcopy       copy databases from one server to another
mysqldbexport     export metadata and data from databases
mysqldbimport     import metadata and data from files
mysqldiff         compare object definitions among objects where the
                  difference is how db1.obj1 differs from db2.obj2
mysqldiskusage    show disk usage for databases
mysqlfailover     automatic replication health monitoring and failover
mysqlfrm          show CREATE TABLE from .frm files
mysqlindexcheck   check for duplicate or redundant indexes
mysqlmetagrep     search metadata
mysqlprocgrep     search process information
mysqlreplicate    establish replication with a master
mysqlrpladmin     administration utility for MySQL replication
mysqlrplcheck     check replication
mysqlrplshow      show slaves attached to a master
mysqlserverclone  start another instance of a running server
mysqlserverinfo   show server information
mysqluserclone    clone a MySQL user account to one or more new users
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql.exe is included in mysql package. You don't have to install anything additionally.

Comment: I don't want to instal the whole mysql database, I only need a client!

Answer (score 0):

download the mysql-5.0.23-win32.zip (this is the smallest possible one) from archived versions in mysql.com website

cut and paste the installation in c drive as mysql folder

then install then follow instructions as per this page:
https://cyleft.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/fixing-mysql-service-could-not-start-1067-errors/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users: 
1.Install the full version of MYSQL
2.On the Windows 10 start button click on search and type in MySQL
3. Select the MYSQL Command Line Client 5.5 (I am using version 5.5)
4. go ahead and run your sql queries/
5. to exit type \q or quit