# my database is in remote server, is it possible to execute queries on dos prompt for remote database

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to execute queries on dos promp for a remote database?

Comment: Possibly, but given that MySQL provides free software for doing this, why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "dos prompt" you mean from the MySQL command line tool.  Yes, it's possible. Here is an example call:

```
mysql -u[user] -p[password] -h [hostname] -D [database] -e "select * from my_table"
```

or if you want to just execute a script file, you would do something like this:

```
mysql -u -p -h remote.host database < yourfile.sql
```

Comment: Need 1 example please

Comment: I thought dos prompt meant the command window on Windows machines.

Comment: It may, but the OP doesn't seem interested in clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mysql installed locally on your windows machine from which you can run something like:

```
/path/to/mysql -h hostname -u username -p password -D database -ss -e "select stuff from thing;"
```

To install mysql on your windows machine you can take a look at this related question:

[MySQL command line client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246482/mysql-command-line-client-for-windows)