# MySQL not recognized in cmd

Tags: mysql, database

I tried to set the path but MySQL doesn't have any bin folder. What should i do?

Problem 1: doesn't have bin folder

[image: doesn't have bin folder]

Problem 2:

[image]

Comment: Did you install mysql server or just mysql workbench?

Comment: can you include the steps you took for the install? the screenshot is good, but generally some info on versions is helpful: windows, mysql, ...

Comment: i'm working on windows + i have mysql-5.7.21 , mySQL workbench 6.3.10 , mySQL developer and oracle 11g

Comment: ok ... problem solved but a new problem has arisen. Its giving an error " Error 2003 <HY000> : cant connect to mysql server on 'localhost' <10061>

Comment: i have also uploaded the screenshot above ...

Comment: are you sure mysql service started? also you might have similar problem as discussed in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246482/mysql-command-line-client-for-windows

Comment: yeah, i think so .... thats why the system asked me for password. I have update the screenshot in problem 2. You can see it there

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows services and make sure that mysql is present there. Ju can restart the service just in case.

If it runs it might be some issue with the localhost access. You can add a user for the localhost. An example:

```
    mysql> CREATE USER 'finley'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'finley'@'localhost'
       WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Have you tried connecting to the database through IDE ?